# Better way to save around 1000 records in a single api

Tags: php, sql

I have a function which saves users phonebook on the server.Now the problem is there are more that 1000 records in one API and it takes too much time to process this function. Is there a better way to insert the data which is fast to do the same process

```
function save_phonebook($data){
$tower=new Tower;
//print_array($data);
$p=json_decode($data['phonebook']);
$phonebook=objectToArray($p);
//print_array($phonebook);
if(count($phonebook)>=1)
{
    foreach($phonebook as $val)
    {
        $rec=array();
        $rec['user_id']=$data['user_id'];
        $rec['name']=$val['name'];
        $rec['mobile']=$val['mobile'];
        $tower->save_user_phonebook_record($rec);

    }
}
$result['status']='success';
$result['message']='Phonebook saved';
$res=json_encode(array($result));
echo $res;
```

The tower class file  code

```
public function save_user_phonebook_record($data)
{
    $mobile=str_replace('+','0',$data['mobile']);
    $mobile=str_replace(' ','',$mobile);
    $mobile=substr($mobile, -10);
    $params = array(':mobile' => $mobile, ':user_id' => $data['user_id']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM friends where mobile=:mobile AND user_id=:user_id";
    $stmt = parent::query($sql, $params);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
        $res=$row;
    endwhile;
    if(count($res)<1)
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO friends (user_id, name, mobile) 
        VALUES(:user_id, :name, :mobile)';
        $params =(array(
            ':user_id' => $data['user_id'],
            ':name' => $data['name'],
            ':mobile' => $mobile
        ));
        parent::query($sql, $params) or die(parent::$dbh->errorInfo());
    }
}
```

The format in which data is recieved which cannot be changed

```
method=save_phonebook,id=1,key=a8d8f8c8c1e129a3b0266455a346fa9d,user_id=25295,phonebook=[{"name":"+91 88264 73159","mobile":"+918826473159"},{"name":"+91 99971 17220","mobile":"+919997117220"},{"name":"+919650088727","mobile":"+919650088727"},{"name":"+919811135060","mobile":"+919811135060"}],
```

Comment: You can always use celery to push this task to background. That way the time to insert doesn't affect the response time of php script :)

Comment: can u please explain a bit and way to imlement it for the above example ?

Comment: sure let me add an answer for the same

Comment: "more than 1000 records in one api"? You mean "in one api **call**" perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Basically from what i see, you have a large amount of data to insert into the database. The `io` operations will always take time and there is no running from it. This leaves you with two options.

- Push uploads in background using ajax call
- Push insert task in background and render page thereby fetching results later

The later is the better solution and you can use celery for the same. Basically celery adds async tasks to the celery server. This way it doesn't matter if the inserts are finished, you can just render the page as it is and worry about the inserts later. Let us assume that you have a 2Mb json file that you need to insert into a database. Now database `IO` are slow. Simply save the file onto disk which is faster and display a page that shows upload in progress and save a flag for same in database.

Create a celery task that reads from file and uploads to database and when it is done with all the insertions, sets the progress save flag to done. Now on frontend side of implementation, If you want to display the results of insertion to user, you can simply check the status flag. If it is set to success by celery, then you can display that the results are uploaded just fine.

Now the complication with this is that `cpanel` based hosting don't usually grant access to root user. There is a workaround for that, by using cron jobs. Make a cron script that will again read data from file and insert into database and set the flag.

The difference between celery and cron is that in case of celery, you can start with insertions as they are uploaded but in case of cron, there will be bulk uploads into the database. [here](https://github.com/gjedeer/celery-php) is a library for celery to get you started in php.

#### EDIT

Some people might say to use `exec` and push the command to background but that again wont be valid because `cpanel` disables that and if you have a server of your own, you are better off with celery than just a hack to get the work done

Comment: is there a way to batch process my function .. .in single query